# StreamHub 2.2.10 comet chat application license

Tags: licensing, chat, comet

I have tried to the comet chat application using streamhub (2.2.10 version), but while doing the compile process it throws an error as

```
StreamHub not started: License has expired
Exception in thread "main" com.streamhub.license.LicenseExpiredException:
License has expired
```

Can any one help me to get the correct license to compile this

i have refered this http://streamhub.blogspot.in/2009/07/tutorial-building-comet-chat.html

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem, 
if you open your licence.txt , y'll probably find some thing like that :
01012011-01012012-10-00 -community-- ...etc
that mean the licence has already expired.

solution : buy a licence or try to get a 60 days trial licence from here http://www.stream-hub.com/eval.html,

Comment: Or stop using streamhub and try atmosphere. If the community edition is free, I shouldn't need to muck around with licenses